# Firebase - Security rule condition for user groups

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have the following collections (ShoppingLists and Users) on a Firebase db:

[image]

[image]

Where the users document ID corresponds to the user's uid.

I tried to restrict the document read/write accesses with the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null 
                  && resource.data.authorizedGroup == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.group;
      
      allow write: if request.auth != null 
                   && resource.data.authorizedGroup == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.group;
    }
  }
}
```

As suggested by egeer in the comments I verified the rule on the emulator and it seems correct (passing the shoppingList document ID and the target user uid, referring to the DB from the first 2 screenshots):

[image]

The goal is to match the field `authorizedGroup`, on the requested document (from the collection ShoppingLists), with the field `group` of users collection, whose ID is the same as the currently logged user's uid.

However, with these security rules, I get an exception when trying to access or edit the documents saying "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions". By looking at the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) about the rules' conditions it seems the correct way to fetch data cross collections, but still, it seems not working as it should.

Here the call to the DB triggering the error:

```
async getActiveList(): Promise<ShoppingList> {

    // This prints correctly the current user
    this.authService.user$.subscribe(u => console.log(u)); 

    const q = query(this.shopListCollection, 
                    where("isActive", "==", true), 

                    // With this condition it works
                    where("authorizedGroup", "==", users.group), 
                    limit(1));

    // This triggers the error
    const docsSnapshots = (await getDocs(q)).docs; 

    // Following code is not reached
    if (docsSnapshots.length > 0) {
      const data = docsSnapshots[0].data() as ShoppingList;

      // Put new list items at the top in their own category
      data.items.sort(this.compareCreatedOn);
      return data;
    }

    return null as ShoppingList;
  }
```

Below is the log of the error:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Following Frank's suggestion I added an extra where condition for the "authorizedGroup" field and documents are properly returned.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that raises that error. In that code, explicitly prove that the current state meets the requirements of your rules (i.e. check that `currentUser` is not null, log what `authorizedGroup` is, and show us the `/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid` doc in the database.

Comment: Just looking at what you have, it looks like the rules are correct. I was able to facilitate what you are trying to do with your rules in my dev environment as well. I agree with @FrankvanPuffelen that your issue is probably with either the path or uid (or perhaps something else) on the client side.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I highly recommend using the Rules Playground or the Emulators to test out your rules to make sure that they are working the way that you want them to: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator  https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the code portion with the query involved in the error. authorizedGroup filed has value "parents" (as seen in the first screenshot) and the currentUser instance is not null (checking it before the query returns a valid instance). Hope this might help to get more hints.

Comment: I suspect you're seeing the effects of [security rules not being filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Since your rules only allow the user to read documents with a specific `authorizedGroup`, your query should filter on that same value.

Comment: It could be, I will check more in detail and give feedback thanks for the hint.

Comment: It works thanks, if you add an answer I will accept it.